# Firefox Addon console.log() Not working

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

So I need to check some results in a Firefox add-on I'm working on, however the console.log() does not work. I've tried simply putting,`console.log("Hello World");` in the main.js file and loading it, but it doesn't log anything.

Comment: Where are you looking for it?  You should be looking at the Firefox console - if it isn't running, there's something wrong with your code that can't be answered based on what you've given so far.

Comment: I'm looking in the console, command/ctrl+shift+j. Regardless if I put it in the main.js file or a content script it doesn't log anything in the console.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By default the minimum log level is `error`. Everything else is not printed, and that includes `console.log()`. Please see the [`Log Levels`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/console#Logging_Levels) for more information on how to use and configure logging and associated levels.

Comment: Thanks, that's very beneficial!

Comment: Wow very beneficial. The `console.time(name)` and `console.timeEnd(name)` feature is awesome. Does `extensions.sdk.console.logLevel` affect non sdk add-ons? Curious because that documentation seems a bit crappy.

Comment: Note that this property of `logLevel` was not visible in my Firefox's `about:config` page (idk why). So, after some time of hunting down the solution, I finally pressed `Ctrl+Shift+J` and it opened the Browser console where I could see logs from my add-on using `console.error`.

Comment: The "Log Levels" link you've given is broken, and I can't find an obvious replacement.  Given the age of this question (and answer), I can speculate that they apply only to pre-WebExtension Firefox add-on development.  Is that the case?

Answer (score 8):

If you are working on an extension/addon (not SDK), simply import the `Console.jsm` and then the `console.log()` will work normally. That is what I do.

```
Components.utils.import('resource://gre/modules/devtools/Console.jsm');
```

**Update:** As of Firefox 44+

```
Components.utils.import('resource://gre/modules/Console.jsm');
```

Comment: I would like to ask, where do I import this? In a content script or in the main script?

Comment: In the main script ususally

Answer (score 3):

You can use Firebug for your firefox extension development. If you install this add-on, you can use its console with "Firebug.Console.log();" command. Please be careful, in this command you should not type "Console" with a small letter!

In addition, you can use Firefox "Browser Console" (not Web Console) by the following command:
Application.console.log();

Answer (score 1):

Using the Addon SDK? You must set the [Log level](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/console#Logging_Levels) for your extension:

```
var self = require("sdk/self"); 
var prefService = require("sdk/preferences/service");  
prefService.set('extensions.'+ self.id +'.sdk.console.logLevel','all');
```